# How can I use React inside a Laravel Nova tool?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible to use React inside a Laravel nova tool?

```
Nova.booting((Vue, router, store) => {
  router.addRoutes([
    {
      name: 'my-tool',
      path: '/my-tool',
      component: require('./components/Tool').default,
    },
  ])
})
```

I don't see how this can be done in with the above `Nova.booting` method. Do you know of any other way?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we chose another approach.